# How to negate the last row in arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I created code that goes through the matrix and sequentially selects the values and combines them.
Now I'm trying to negate the last column by multiplying it by -1

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14,15],
                [21, 22, 23, 24,25],
                [31, 32, 33, 34,35],
                [41, 42, 43, 44,45],
                [51, 52, 53, 54,55]])

a=[np.column_stack([arr[:-1, :n], arr[1:, n-1]]) for n in range(1,4)]
```

my output

```
[array([[11, 21],
        [21, 31],
        [31, 41],
        [41, 51]]),
 array([[11, 12, 22],
        [21, 22, 32],
        [31, 32, 42],
        [41, 42, 52]]),
 array([[11, 12, 13, 23],
        [21, 22, 23, 33],
        [31, 32, 33, 43],
        [41, 42, 43, 53]])]
```

required output

```
[array([[11, -21],
        [21, -31],
        [31, -41],
        [41, -51]]),
 array([[11, 12, -22],
        [21, 22, -32],
        [31, 32, -42],
        [41, 42, -52]]),
 array([[11, 12, 13, -23],
        [21, 22, 23, -33],
        [31, 32, 33, -43],
        [41, 42, 43, -53]])]
```

this is my attempt at negation

```
a=a[:,-1]*-1
```

this is my error message printed out to me

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: You can give `arr[-1] *= -1` to negate the last row

Comment: You can also give `arr[:,-1] *= -1` to negate the last column

Comment: sorry, column, no line

Comment: still the error message: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Are you giving the statement correctly?

Comment: `a=[:,-1]*-1` I think this statement is missing the array you are looking into

Comment: `a` is a list. you can't use mixed indices `[:,-1]`. Instead, use list comprehension. i.e. `a=[np.concatenate([row[:-1], -row[-1:]]) for row in a]`.

Comment: `for v in a: v[:,-1] *= -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `-` right in front of `arr[1:, n-1]`

```
a = [np.column_stack([arr[:-1, :n], -arr[1:, n-1]]) for n in range(1, 4)]
```

Output:

```
[array([[ 11, -21],
       [ 21, -31],
       [ 31, -41],
       [ 41, -51]]), 
array([[ 11,  12, -22],
       [ 21,  22, -32],
       [ 31,  32, -42],
       [ 41,  42, -52]]), 
array([[ 11,  12,  13, -23],
       [ 21,  22,  23, -33],
       [ 31,  32,  33, -43],
       [ 41,  42,  43, -53]])]
```

Comment: Yes, since this is a column_stack, the last column can be negated to get the answer. Good call

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.

Input:

```
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

Last row: `arr[-1] *= -1`

Output :

```
array([[ 11,  12,  13,  14,  15],
       [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25],
       [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35],
       [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45],
       [-51, -52, -53, -54, -55]])
```

Last column : `arr[:,-1] *= -1`

Output:

```
array([[ 11,  12,  13,  14, -15],
       [ 21,  22,  23,  24, -25],
       [ 31,  32,  33,  34, -35],
       [ 41,  42,  43,  44, -45],
       [ 51,  52,  53,  54, -55]])
```

You are stacking it this way using:

```
a=[np.column_stack([arr[:-1, :n], arr[1:, n-1]]) for n in range(1,4)]

[array([[11, 21],
       [21, 31],
       [31, 41],
       [41, 51]]), 
array([[11, 12, 22],
       [21, 22, 32],
       [31, 32, 42],
       [41, 42, 52]]), 
array([[11, 12, 13, 23],
       [21, 22, 23, 33],
       [31, 32, 33, 43],
       [41, 42, 43, 53]])]
```

Since you want to change the values for only the last column in each element of the array, you can iterate through it and change it.

```
for i in range (len(a)): a[i][:,-1] *= -1
```

The output of this will be:

```
[array([[ 11, -21],
       [ 21, -31],
       [ 31, -41],
       [ 41, -51]]), 
array([[ 11,  12, -22],
       [ 21,  22, -32],
       [ 31,  32, -42],
       [ 41,  42, -52]]), 
array([[ 11,  12,  13, -23],
       [ 21,  22,  23, -33],
       [ 31,  32,  33, -43],
       [ 41,  42,  43, -53]])]
```

Comment: yes, but I need to negate in the required output, and there he throws me an error message

Comment: I see the new output ask. let me update the answer to show that

Comment: how can i give you permission?

Comment: see changes now

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `a`:

`a =` **a**`[:,-1]*-1`

Comment: Oh, a is a list of arrays. Try do that  for each of arrays. You can use `for` loop to do that.